# I want to build a student attendence monitoring system using google site

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites

I want to build a student attendence monitoring system using google site. I need a help for that..I can't understand from where to start. I made a site. made a form for student registration and attached it to my site...the response sheet is also attached with it..then blank...

JavaScript is not running on HTML view. I don't know how to enable it.

so plzz help me to run java script and also give me the idea what I should do after this..

I want a page on my site that collect students' data with daily attendance. with a submit button that data will be stored in a spresdsheet automatically. and making another page where I will see the details of a particular student.

Thank you.. :)

Comment: This question is far too vague for this site

Comment: We want to help you, but your question is kind of like asking, "Please teach me algebra, but I don't know how to add numbers."  We can't do it.  JavaScript not running in HTML view could be a question of it's own.

Comment: I know that, I another thing I came to know is that, java script runs on google site but some of its features are not supporting on google site...that was a problem...I'm a google app script learner. but I can't embedding those on google site to do my project.. please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate JavaScript on your Google Sites.
You need to have Google App Engine with Python

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/?hl=fr
With this you can take a page in Html With Javascript.

you said  :
"I want a page on my site that collect students' data with daily attendance. with a submit button that data will be stored in a spresdsheet automatically. and making another page where I will see the details of a particular student."

---

You can do this in App Script  with : 
- Ui Form       -   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/?hl=FR
- HTML Service      -  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/